# Bootstrap Carousel image resize loses full-width

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

The images in the Bootstrap Carousel on this page fill the width when the page first loads and are of the correct aspect ratio: http://mj-test.azurewebsites.net/

When you resize the browser to small and go back to full width on the browser, the image shrinks, with black bars on left and right side. It needs to keep the image full-width as when the page loaded. I've looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274598/bootstrap-carousel-image-not-display-in-full-width), and applied this CSS, but it distorts the image (stretches the width) when the browser is shrunk, then back to full width:

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

I've also looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875840/bootstrap-carousel-image-resizing) (`width:100%` on image), but it causes the image to run under the menu. Here's the simplified carousel HTML:

```
<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="slideshow-carousel-1" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item item-1 slide-image active">
            <img class="img-responsive bg-item parallax" data-width="1970" data-height="1290" src="~/images/slideshow/baby-close-fade.jpg" alt="Slide 1 Background">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h1 class="title">Caption text</h1>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

There's this code being called on window resize:

```
$(window).on('resize', imageFit);
```

but I don't know how that's causing these issues. Help is appreciated. Thanks.